# jurabib: every field in a new line

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, jurabib

I'm trying to make use of some of the features of jurabib-package which are quite essential for me now. But I'm still facing one problem:

I use the package with the `bibformat=tabular`, which nearly gives me the result I'm looking for; the one thing I'm still missing is to be able to output every single field from the bib-file in a *separate*, so in a new line (which would make it even more "tabular").

Unfortunately, I couldn't find no native option ([here](http://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/jurabib/jb-opt-ref.html)) to realize this. So instead, there might be a way to do this by editing some of the jurabib style / bst files i recon, but I've got no clue where and what to do.

So again, this is the bibliography-look I want to achieve:

```
**Bibliography**

Lastname, Firstname      Title
                         Edition
                         Adress
                         etc.
```

(of course, this should apply to all the different entry types which do exist)

In case it's helpful, here is a MWE which I tried to create from my (huge) tex file:

```
\documentclass[
  widefront,
  tightfn
]{jura}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[see]{jurabib}

\jurabibsetup{
  titleformat={commasep,all},
  commabeforerest,
  crossref={long,dynamic},
  howcited=compare, 
  pages={always,test}, 
  bibformat={tabular,ibidem},
  lookforgender,
  dotafter=bibentry,
}
\citetitlefortype{article,periodical,incollection}
\formatpages[~]{article}{(}{)} 
\formatpages[~]{incollection}{(}{)}
\renewcommand{\bibjtsep}{In: } 
\renewcommand{\bibbtsep}{In: } 
\renewcommand*{\bibpldelim}{(}
\renewcommand*{\bibprdelim}{)}
\renewcommand*{\bibleftcolumn}{\textwidth/3}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\jbaensep}{,}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\artnumberformat}[1]{(#1)}
\AddTo\bibsgerman{\def\ajtsep{}}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle[{jurabib}

\newpage

\mainmatter

\cite{testbibkey}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Astonishing that jurabib is still around. Maybe you used some old documentation. Be aware that the most recent version of jurabib is 0.6 dating back to January 2004. The project homepage at sourceforge lists it as “inactive”.

I would strongly recommend switching to *biblatex*. I switched to it from jurabib around 5 years ago and I don’t miss a feature.

As most people use biblatex this would increase your changes of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Well I already used to work with biber / BibLaTeX before, but right now, I got really comfortable with jurabib since it was just right for my studies at uni (law). I think it would be quite hard work to realize all that without jurabib itself, wouldn't it?

Comment: If anyone could give me a detailed explanation of how to move from jurabib to BibLaTex, I'd go that way immediately. But there's a lot of trouble wich - right now - I don't know how to work around; like e.g. the tabular bibliography I mentioned above, the in-text-citations which look like `author1/author2: title, edition` and so on... is there any tutorial or such where I could get hold of all these informations. I didn't really manage to get into the customization of the biblatex-style files yet on my own